# Fetching comments of a post through ajax from database in laravel 5.3

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel, laravel-5.3

```
<script>
    var token = '{{ Session::token() }}';
    var commentUrl = '{{ route('comments.store')  }}';
    var fetchComments = '{{ route('commentT')  }}';

</script>
```

A 'post' route to fetch comment

```
Route::post('comm', [
                'uses' => 'CommentController@comment',
                'as'   => 'commentT'
            ]);
```

function which has ajax

```
function getCommentsFromDb(postid){

    console.log("Post"+postid);
    $.ajax({

        type : 'POST',
        url  : fetchComments,
        data : { postid: postid,_token: token },
        success : function(result){
            console.log(result);
        }

    });

}
```

I am trying to fetch comments of a single post and i am passing id of post

```
 public function comment(Request $request)
    {
        //

            $answer_id = $request['answerid'];

            // echo "controller side ".$test;

            $comments = DB::table('posts')
                        ->join('posts', 'posts.id' , '=', 'comments.answer_id')
                        ->join('users' , 'users.id' , '=', 'comments.user_id')
                        ->where('posts.id', '=' , $post_id)
                        ->select('comments.comment as comment',
                                'comments.created_at as created_at',
                                'users.first_name as first_name',
                                'users.last_name as last_name',
                                'posts.post as post')
                        ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
                        ->get();

                   $comm = json_decode($comments);

                   print_r($comm);

        *// I though here i have to write html content which i want to render on the view* 


    }
```

I am getting expected result in console but how can i render this result to my view , it is simple if i do in core php but here in laravel i am stuck

In future i would be making delete,edit functionality for comments using ajax

Here is what i am getting in mys console

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [comment] => sdfasdf shameem
            [created_at] => 2017-03-31 21:44:22
            [first_name] => Shameem
            [last_name] => Ansari
            [post]  => fist post content fist post content fist post content fist post content fist post content fist post content fist post content fist post content 
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [comment] => game on
            [created_at] => 2017-03-31 21:22:44
            [first_name] => Waqaar
            [last_name] => Aslam
            [post]    => fist post content fist post content fist post content fist post content fist post content fist post content fist post content fist post content
        )

)
```

i assume first i have to put these values that i got in console in html structure as i want comment section format to be and then i can do this #div_to_show

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want to show comments in the page.

1. You can use the GET method instead of the POST method. (While you are getting data, You don't submit any POST data.)
2. Instead of `console.log(result);` or below of `console.log(result);` add $`('#div_to_show').html(result);` where `div_to_show` is the id of the div tag.
3. You can return JSON data and append them with jQuery. (Good idea if you want to use Ajax.)

Code:

```
function getCommentsFromDb(postid){
    console.log("Post"+postid);
    $.ajax({

        type : 'POST',
        url  : fetchComments,
        data : { postid: postid,_token: token },
        success : function(result){
            console.log(result);
            $('#div_to_show').html(result); // If it is json try      $.each(result, function(i, field){$("#div_to_show").append(field + " ");});
        }
    });
}
```

php code:

```
 public function comment(Request $request)
    {
        //

            $answer_id = $request['answerid'];

            // echo "controller side ".$test;

            $comments = DB::table('posts')
                        ->join('posts', 'posts.id' , '=', 'comments.answer_id')
                        ->join('users' , 'users.id' , '=', 'comments.user_id')
                        ->where('posts.id', '=' , $post_id)
                        ->select('comments.comment as comment',
                                'comments.created_at as created_at',
                                'users.first_name as first_name',
                                'users.last_name as last_name',
                                'posts.post as post')
                        ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
                        ->get();

                   $comms = json_decode($comments);

                   //Instead of print_r()
                   foreach($comments as $comment) {
                       echo "<div>";
                       echo $comment->first_name;
                       echo $comment->last_name;
                       echo $comment->comment;
                       echo $comment->created_at;
                       echo "</div>";
                   }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks Ali can you have a look again i have edited my question

Comment: thanks Ali, that's what i needed, i was making mistakes in single quote and double quote :p